# Glass not see through around corners of mesh in eevee

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, glass

[image: Corner of mesh]

I cant see through parts of the window in eevee and I have enabled screen space refraction.

Comment: In the material, under Settings, there's a Refraction Depth value, what does it give if you play with it?

Comment: That's done it, just had to increase the refraction depth slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Material* panel, under *Settings*, increase the *Refraction Depth* value.